# Unable to install google-api-client gem latest versions along with appnexusapi gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api-client, faraday

I have an application which is using Appnexusapi gem. Now I need to install google-api-client gem(>= 0.8.2) into my application to connect google adx api. But while installing google-api-client I am getting dependency issues with faraday and multi_json gems. Can any one provide me solution to this issue.

Please find the below error I am getting

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
 In Gemfile:
    appnexusapi (>= 0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (~> 1.0.3) ruby

    google-api-client (= 0.8.2) ruby depends on
      multi_json (1.10.0)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the author of appnexusapi to update to a later version of multi_json.  While you wait, you can try forking it yourself, updating the gemspec and then specifying your fork as the gem source. If you are able to make it work with the latest version of multi_json (I can't see any tests) then you could send a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gerry . But If I update gemspec of appnexusapi the  internal methods of appnexusapi are not working

Comment: Unfortunately this means somebody has to fix those internal methods. However this is odd considering multijson claims that minor releases should not break anything (https://github.com/intridea/multi_json#versioning). It might be any easy fix in Appnexusapi. Give it a shot